# How can I make Safari show the URL when I hover over a link?

Tags: macos, safari

Safari 5.0.1 on OS X Snow Leopard (10.6) doesn't seem to have any status bar in which the URL of a link shows when the user moves the cursor over a link (without clicking)   All other browsers I've ever used do this.

Is there a user preference checkbox somewhere for this?

Comment: BTW, I'm using Safari 5.0.1 on Snow Leopard, in case that matters.

Comment: Works on macOS Catalina as well  :o)

Comment: Still upvoting in Monterey

Answer (score 370, accepted):

There are two options. One is a setting, and the other is a workaround.

Here are instructions on how to toggle the setting using the Menu Bar:

1. Go into the View menu.
2. Select "Show status bar".
3. Now, there will be a URL that pops up when you hover over a link, and also tells you if it's going to be in a new tab:

[image]

You can also press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to toggle this setting at ease.

The second option is a workaround for when you drag links. Here's how to get this feature to appear:

1. Click and drag the link out of where it will originally appear.
2. At your mouse will be a small box telling you the title of the new window and its URL, although it may be shortened.
3. You can also drag the link to the plus sign in your tab list, out of the window, or in a folder/the desktop to open that URL in a new tab, new window or save it to your computer, respectively.

Comment: Good, useful tips, but after seeing the slickness of Ultimate Status Bar, I'm sold on that, especially un-tinying tiny urls.

Comment: I prefer this answer if only need to show link destination. Use native feature if possible, extention may adding memory usage.

Comment: Aw yeah. Great info. :)

Comment: This information is still valid as of Safari 9.1.2

Comment: This information is still valid as of Safari 11.0

Comment: Why would this be turned off by default requiring a google search to turn it on? Being able to see where a link goes *before* clicking it is crucial for security/privacy. Wtf is Apple thinking?

Comment: @devios1 makes for a cleaner UI. Also makes it more consistent with iOS - you don't automatically see URLs before tapping a link on iOS.

Comment: This information is still valid as of Safari 14.0

Comment: This information is still valid as of Safari 15.1.

Comment: On German keyboard, the toggle shortcut is `cmd+ß` which is **strong s**.

Comment: This information is still valid as of Safari 17.1

Answer (score 19):

I believe this **Safari Extension** did precisely what you are looking to do, but it's now abandoned:
[Ultimate Status Bar](http://web.archive.org/web/20120107051251/http://ultimatestatusbar.com/).

Comment: Hey, that extension does precisely what I'm looking for!  +1

Comment: I can confirm it works with Yosemite and Safari 8.

Answer (score 11):

The URL of links your hover over is shown on the gray status bar at the bottom of the page. The status bar is not always present in a new window, but you can turn it on from View > Show Status Bar or with the <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> shortcut.

Some pages can hide the status bar and it does not restore if you go to a new window. However File->New Window should always show this.

Comment: It is not always present in a new window. However, it is user-toggleable (**View** > **Show Status Bar**; or the ⌘/ shortcut).

Comment: Duplicate answer of https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/16775/489896

Comment: @Thinkr How - it predates the other answer. The other is the duplicate but covers more than this

Comment: @mmmmmm If you check the [timeline](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/16761/revisions) of your answer, I see the answer which is shown now (View > Show Status Bar) was added after the other post. Yours : **November 14th 2014**; Other answer : **June 30th 2011**

Comment: @Thinkr my original is Jun 29 and the newer on Jun 30 - the edit was probably because I got a notification and looked at this answer only an edited.

Comment: @mmmmmm On June 29, your answer did not contain the parts of the other answer yet.