# How do I enable preview of URL in a popup?

Tags: macos, safari

I just noticed that when I hover with my cursor over a link, I don't get the url. I tried in maximized (full screen) and normal mode, and it doesn't show up in a popup or in a bottom bar as it does on Firefox. It's a bit annoying of course. I know about [snowleopard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16759/how-can-i-make-safari-show-the-url-when-i-hover-over-a-link)'s behavior, has Apple changed their stance or is still an external plugin the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable the status bar you can see the target URL without plugin. You might prefer the plugin still though.

To enable, go to the View menu and click "Show Status Bar".

Comment: Yes, that's the behavior from the link I put in my question. What I wanted was to have the bar show up only if I need it, or a popup. Is that at all possible?

Comment: With the plugin it is.

Comment: OK, then plugin it shall be. Thanks for your advice :D

Comment: Newer versions of Safari (tested on Sierra and High Sierra) do not need a plugin to do this. The bar only shows up when needed by default. I would guess this was introduced with Mavericks or Yosemite, but I haven't tested on them.

Edit: I have found a thread on Redditwhich in which people mention this feature having been introduced in El Capitan. There used to be a persistent bar on the bottom, and now it's only shown when necessary (and it doesn't take the whole bottom, either).

https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/3jqyxe/safari_on_el_capitan_public_beta_now_shows_links/